# Comments in pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a very simple grammar. Basically it's made up of blocks, each of which
starts with `&` and some name, and extends down to the next one or to the end
of the file. In addition, there are comments of two kinds: one-line comments,
from a `*` to the end of the line, and C-style comments, enclosed in `/* */`.
The comments can be inside the blocks too. My try so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pyparsing import *

NL = Suppress( LineEnd() )
restOfLineNL = restOfLine + NL

LineComment = Literal('*') + restOfLineNL
BlockComment = nestedExpr('/*', '*/')
Comment = BlockComment | LineComment

ModuleName = LineStart() + Word( '&', alphanums + '_', min=2 ) + NL
Module = ModuleName + SkipTo( StringEnd() | ModuleName, include=False)
Grammar = ZeroOrMore( Module )
Grammar.ignore(Comment)

result = Grammar.parseString('''
&keyword1

*comment

&keyword2
arbitrary lines
* with comments interspersed
possibly empty

/*
&keyword3
c-style comments
are allowed too
*/

&keyword4

''', parseAll=False)

for line in result:
  print('|'+line.rstrip()+'|')
```

this results in:

```
|&keyword1|
||
|&keyword2|
|arbitrary lines
* with comments interspersed
possibly empty

/|
|&keyword3|
|c-style comments
are allowed too|
|&keyword4|
||
```

which has a couple of problems:

1. The comment inside &keyword2 is not removed.
2. The C-style comment around &keyword3 is not removed.

Any ideas how to fix this? Or some alternative python package to parse this kind of file?

Comment: PyParsing supports C-Style comments: https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing-module.html#cStyleComment